# getting POST datas in java Spring Rest Server from $.fileDownload

Tags: java, spring, rest, download

I've wrote an application for download file using **[jQuery File Download v1.2.0](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-v1-2-0-released-and-on-github/)** plugin.
In jQuery File Download v1.2.0 we have an option for send datas as POST

**POST request with data and query string**

```
$.fileDownload('/GetAFoo?a=b', { httpMethod : "POST", data: { foo : "bar"}})
```

can anyone please tell me how to receive the post datas on the server side, i'm using Java Spring Rest Server

my code is as given below

**script**

```
var json ="[[\"Name\",\"Place\",\"Phone\"]," + "[\"AAA\",\"hhh\",\"123\"]," + "[\"BBB\",\"\",\"254\"]," + "[\"CCC\",\"'#?\",\"\"]]";
    $.fileDownload(URL,{ httpMethod : "POST", data: { excelContent : json}}).done(function(e, response)
    {
    }).fail(function(e, response)
    {
    });
```

**Java Spring Rest**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "fileDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APP_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public void getMyFileDownload(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, Exception
{
        //how to get the content of excelContent over here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is jee not spring, but I think it almost the same

```
    @GET
    @Path("download")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response exportScenario(@Context final HttpServletResponse resp) {
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        return Response.ok(new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(final OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                // place to write file data into stream
            }
        }).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"").build();
    }
```

Update:
Browser side:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'rest/configuration/add.json',
    type : 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : $.toJSON({
        title : $('#conf_create_name')[0].value, 
        comment : $('#conf_create_comment')[0].value,
        params : params
    }),
});
```

Ajax post reauset with json object $.toJSON need additional jquery plugin search google.

Server side:

```
    @POST
    @Path("download")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response exportScenario(@Context final HttpServletResponse resp, final ConfigurationDTO confDTO) {
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        return Response.ok(new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(final OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                // place to write file data into stream
            }
        }).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"").build();
    }
```

ConfigeratioDTO:

```
public class ConfigurationDTO {
    private String title;
    private String comment;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

Comment: but we are using Spring

Comment: also where do we get the json string which is passed

Comment: Spring use the same package javax.ws.rs annotations and code will be the same. Just write content of your file into OutputStream.

Comment: Make method @POST add annotation @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   and add your json to request params. And read it into method as parameter

Comment: but i'm not using $.ajax i'm using $.fileDownload

Comment: What the problem use fileDownload in case of example it will be like $.fileDownload('/rest/download', { httpMethod : "post", data: $.toJSON({foo : "bar"})})

Comment: can you please show me how to write the server side for receiving the json with spring rest ....

Comment: since we are using Spring Rest server ...and the code is like...`@RequestMapping(value = "fileDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APP_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public void getMyFileDownload(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, Exception
{
        //how to get the content of excelContent over here
}`

Comment: Sorry I never use Spring rest server. If it use different method signature I can't help.

Comment: since im looking for that stuff with Spring Rest server code

Answer (score 0):

If you recibe in your service you file as a Output Stream you can do something like that. It is working for me in one of my projects.
The most importante part is:

```java
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
fileStream.writeTo( out );
```

from the response you can get some Streams and output types

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getFile")
    public void getFile(FilterDTO filter, HttpServletResponse response) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream fileStream = yourService.returnFile( filter );

        try {
            String fileNamePdf = "FileName.pdf";
            response.setHeader( "Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" fileNamePdf );
            response.setContentType("your application/pdf or xls or extension" );

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            fileStream.writeTo( out );

            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
            throw new Exception( //your exception implementation );
        }
    }
```

adapting it a little bit to your code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/fileDownload")
    public void getMyFileDownload(HttpServletResponse response) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream fileStream = yourService.returnFile();

        try {
            String fileNamePdf = "FileName.pdf";
            response.setHeader( "Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" fileNamePdf );
            response.setContentType("your application/pdf or xls or extension" );

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            fileStream.writeTo( out );

            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
            throw new Exception( //your exception implementation );
        }
    }
```